# How to loop VBA code for different columns/sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Let me preface this with that I am by no means a developer/code writer, so I am running on the barest of bones when it comes to understanding everything.

In an excel sheet I am creating for work, I am using code that checks cells for their color based on conditional formatting, then changes the color of the cells in another sheet to match them. I went with a macro vs CF due to the number of columns/rows that are being controlled, and to let each person using the sheet customize the color to what they prefer without having to change hundreds of lines to do it.

The code I am using is :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xWRg, xDERg, xlWRg, xlDERg As Range
Dim xfnum As Long
'On Error Resume Next
Set xDERg = Sheets("Data Entry").Range("D9:D200")
Set xWRg = Sheets("Worksheet").Range("E6:E200")
For xfnum = 1 To xWRg.Count
    Set xlWRg = xWRg.Cells.Item(xfnum)
    Set xlDERg = xDERg.Cells.Item(xfnum)
    xlDERg.Interior.Color = xlWRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
Next xfnum

End Sub
```

I have it working for that specific range, but I also need it to check G9:G200 on Data Entry and K6:K200 on the worksheet, a long with a couple other columns. There are 7 total ranges that need to be controlled by this.

Comment: Any reason why you would use a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` for this code?  This uses `Target` as an input to execute the code.

Comment: I found this code after searching Google for awhile. I was able to somewhat understand what was happening, and was able to get it to work. If there is a cleaner/easier method for this, I am all for it.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What worksheet is this code in? What cell or range are you using to activate the `SelectionChange` event? Your code does not `check` the cells, it just copies the interior color to the destination range. Also, if you are looping through two ranges, they need to be the same size. Your code loops through each item in range `E6:E200` 195 items, but range `D9:D200` has only 192 items. You need to provide more information to include the other ranges you want to copy the interior color from/to.

Comment: The code is based in the sheet "Worksheet". Worksheet cell range E6:E200 determines the color of the cells in Data Entry D9:200 (I can make them the same total cell range, that would not be a problem). My end goal is to have Worksheet ranges E6:E200, K6:K200, Q6:Q200, W6:W200, AC6:AC200, AI6:A200, & AO6:AO200 determine the color of Data Entry D6:D200, G6:G200, J6:J200, M6:M200, P6:P200, S6:S200 & V6:V200 respectively. The end cells can be changed so the total range remains equal. 200 is probably overkill.

Comment: If the ranges in all the columns are the same size you can use a `last row` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code rewritten to clean it up. ***Note:*** If your destination range is smaller then the source range, then cells below the destination range may be colored.

```
Dim xWRg As Range: Set xWRg = Sheets("Worksheet").Range("E6:E200") 'Set your source range
Dim xDERg As Range: Set xDERg = Sheets("Data Entry").Range("D9:D203") 'Set your destination range, usaually same number of cells

    For xfnum = 1 To xWRg.Count 'loop through the number of items in source range
        
        'copy the conditional formating color to the destination range
        xDERg.Item(xfnum).Interior.Color = xWRg.Item(xfnum).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        
    Next xfnum 'loop
```

If you could clarify what sheet/range will activate the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, and the additional five ranges you need to add, I can provide better guidance, it depends on the layout of the ranges you want to work with.

Comment: The activation on the selection change is updating cells within the "Worksheet" tab. I believe specifically selecting a cell (any cell i think) within "Worksheet" will cause the macro to fire.

Comment: I put that code in and was able to manipulate it to make it work for what I was after. You answered my question perfectly. Thank you!